# Setting gnu screen split by default

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Is there a way in say a .screenrc file to simulate the following commands?

```
screen
(ctrl + a) + :split
(ctrl + a) + tab
(ctrl + a) + c
(ctrl + a) + tab
(ctrl + a) + :resize 10
```

Basically what it does is opens up screen, splits the window in half, creates a new shell in the split window and then resizes the new split to 10 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got it:

```
startup_message off
screen
split
focus
screen
resize 10
focus
```